# React native form using useState

Tags: react-native

React native form. Keep the same format React.useState and update the input. In react it is possible to do it. Is possible to do in react native?

```
 import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Input, Text, Button } from "react-native-elements";
import Spacer from "../Spacer";
const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const { name, email, password } = formData;

  const handleChange = name => e => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: e.target.value });
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Spacer>
        <Text h4 style={styles.header}>
          Register
        </Text>
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer>
        <Input
          label="Name"
          value={name}
          onChangeText={() => handleChange("name")}
        />
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer>
        <Input
          label="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={() => handleChange("email")}
        />
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer>
        <Input
          label="Password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={() => handleChange("password")}
        />
      </Spacer>
      <Spacer>
        <Button title="Sign Up" />
      </Spacer>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginBottom: 150
  },
  header: {
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});

export default RegisterScreen;
```

(React native form. Keep the same format React.useState and update the input. In react it is possible to do it. Is possible to do in react native?)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! it should work fine! Just import `useState`, which is missing in your code.